# How to link a Visual Basic 6 Combo box with a field in a Microsoft Access 2007 Table

Tags: ms-access, vb6, combobox, database-connection

There is a Teacher Table in Microsoft Access 2007. And i want to get all the names of the Teachers from the field Tch_name to a combo box list in VB6. Does a loop needs to be created? Can anyone help me out please.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
 dim db as new adodb.connection

    'then open your database with db connection
    dim r as new adodb.recordset
    r.open "select Name from Teacher", db, adopendynamic, adlockoptimistic, adcmdtext

    'I guess column name is Name
    do while not r.eof
        combo1.additem(r.fields(0))
        r.movenext
    loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution--I did vote it up, as it's the method I'd use for the purpose (though I'd prob'ly use the field name instead of its ordinal in the AddItem loop). Your next assignment on the new-user learining curve is "code formatting".