# Retrieve data from database(MS Access 2007) using Combobox -2 style. VB6 and populate other content into textbox

Tags: combobox, vb6, ms-access-2007, populate

I have already tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758690/how-to-link-a-visual-basic-6-combo-box-with-a-field-in-a-microsoft-access-2007-t/5777006#5777006) and receive a lot of errors. I need this school project again. Also I need to know how to open it's connection in module.

Here's my code for module:

```
Global aRs1 As New ADODB.Recordset

Public Sub filler1()
Set aCon1 = New ADODB.Connection
aCon1.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
App.Path & "\employee.mdb;"

End Sub
```

My table name is employeeName

it has ID, FirstName, and LastName.

What I wanna do now is that when i Click my combobox(cboID1), it will retrieve the data(ID) from my database(employee). Once i have chosen the ID, it will then automatically put the Firstname and lastname into the respective textboxes.(txtFName and txtLName).

```
  ANSWERS NEEDED: how to retrieve data from database using combobox, then putting the corresponding items to textboxes with respect to combobx, and database connection for this.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried and which bit are you stuck on. I've you've tried code already, what errors are you getting?

Comment: I don't know where to startnow. Im very confused already. The very main problem is that I don't know how to get data from database using cbbox.. I have tried this code, which i got here on stack
Set aRs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
With aRs1
.ActiveConnection = aCon1
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.CursorType = adOpenStatic
.LockType = adLockPessimistic
.Source = "SELECT ID FROM EmployeeName WHERE ID=" & "'" & cboId1.Text & "'"
.Open
txtFname.Text = aRs1("FirstName")
End With

The error i receive is Argument are of the wrong type, out of acceptable range....The error is here .ActiveConnection = aCon1

Comment: Link the table. Use the wizards.

Comment: You are using MS Access, there are wizards for linking tables, for forms and for creating comboboxes.

Comment: Are you actually writing the app in VBA/Access or VB6? they will have completely different frameworks. As for the combobox population, the answer you linked to explains that and gives samples. Is that working ok? If so, it's fairly simple to duplicate that to get a specific record and set two text boxes.